# Get users Cognito Pool Groups in old API Gateway integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am working on updating some old API's that are built using the "aws" integration, which provides a super basic way of passing data via a POST method, where the atached Lambda's `event` object is literally just the JSON payload that was sent.

For context, our newer APIs use `aws_proxy` which contains a lot more information in the `event` and importantly, includes the cognito username and groups in `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims`.

I need to be able to find these details in the old APIs with as least distruption as possible.

I have tried the mapping template below, but logging out the `event` afterwards, results in most of `context` being empty. No Coginto Pool details were to be seen.

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }
}
```

I don't mind having to modify the Lambda functions somewhat, as I will need to do that anyway as part of the updates we are doing. The one thing I can't really do is convert these to `aws_proxy` as it requires a lot more work to fix the response payloads, and our Frontend would need to do a ton fo work to read and parse the new responses.

Simply put; how can I get the authorzed callers Cognito Pool Groups from an old `aws` API Gateway integration?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was close, but the magic mapping was the following:

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
    "body" : $input.json('$'),
    "username": "$context.authorizer.claims["cognito:username"]",
    "groups": "$context.authorizer.claims["cognito:groups"]"
}
```